# R notebook html only display code but doesn't show output

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, rnotebook

I m trying to run basic `summary()` function with r notebook.
When ı run the code, its works properly and ı can see code and output on the console but when ı look at the preview I can just see code and output of summary function does not display

And a screenshot:[image]

[image]

Anyone knows how I can solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Try to click "Run all" from the drop down menu in the top right corner. Does this help? I've the impression that sometimes RStudio doesn't caches the outputs correctly

Comment: If you knit to HTML once, the preview will work afterwards. Preview doesn't recalculate the whole document but uses already evaluated cache.

Comment: I did what u both said but still does not work.Neither on preview nor on knit to html

Comment: Click on the gear icon next to the green arrow, this gives you some options for output, play with those and see if anything works. Also maybe try creating a new notebook in a new directory and see if that works